# Using python lime as a udf on spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pickle, dill

I'm looking to use [lime's](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime/) `explainer` within a udf on pyspark. I've previously trained the tabular explainer, and stored is as a dill model as suggested in [link](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime/issues/98)

```
loaded_explainer = dill.load(open('location_to_explainer','rb'))

def lime_explainer(*cols):
    selected_cols = np.array([value for value in cols])
    exp = loaded_explainer.explain_instance(selected_cols, loaded_model.predict_proba, num_features = 10)
    mapping = exp.as_map()[1]

    return str(mapping)
```

This however takes a lot of time, as it appears a lot of the computation happens on the driver. I've then been trying to use spark broadcast to broadcast the explainer to the executors.

```
broadcasted_explainer= sc.broadcast(loaded_explainer)

def lime_explainer(*col):
    selected_cols = np.array([value for value in cols])
    exp = broadcasted_explainer.value.explain_instance(selected_cols, loaded_model.predict_proba, num_features = 10)
    mapping = exp.as_map()[1]

    return str(mapping)
```

However, I run into a pickling error, on broadcast.

> PicklingError: Can't pickle  at 0x7f69fd5680d0>:
>   attribute lookup  on lime.discretize failed

Can anybody help with this? Is there something like `dill` that we can use instead of the cloudpickler used in spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/broadcast.py#L112), it seems like you have no choice but to use the pickler provided. As such, I can only suggest that you nest dill inside of the default pickler. Not ideal, but it could work. Try something like:

```
broadcasted_explainer = dill.loads(sc.broadcast(dill.dumps(loaded_explainer)).value)
```

Or you might try calling the [Dill extend() method](https://dill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#dill.extend) which is supposed to add Dill datatypes into the default pickle package dispatch. No idea if that will work but you can try it!

Answer (score 3):

I'm the `dill` author.  I agree with @Majaha, and will extend @Majaha's answer slightly. In the first link in @Majaha's answer, it's clearly pointed out that a `Broadcast` instance is hardwired to use `pickle`... so the suggestion to `dill` to a string, then un`dill` afterward is a good one.

Unfortunately, the `extend` method probably won't work for you.  In the `Broadcast` class, the source uses `CPickle`, which `dill` cannot extend.
If you look at the source, it uses `import CPickle as pickle; ... pickle.dumps` for python 2, and `import pickle; ... pickle.dumps` for python 3. Had it used `import pickle; ... pickle.dumps` for python 2, and `import pickle; ... pickle._dumps` for python 3, then `dill` could extend the pickler by just doing an `import dill`. For example:

```
Python 3.6.6 (default, Jun 28 2018, 05:53:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pickle import _dumps
>>> import dill
>>> _dumps(lambda x:x)
b'\x80\x03cdill._dill\n_create_function\nq\x00(cdill._dill\n_load_type\nq\x01X\x08\x00\x00\x00CodeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04(K\x01K\x00K\x01K\x01KCC\x04|\x00S\x00q\x05N\x85q\x06)X\x01\x00\x00\x00xq\x07\x85q\x08X\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>q\tX\x08\x00\x00\x00<lambda>q\nK\x01C\x00q\x0b))tq\x0cRq\rc__main__\n__dict__\nh\nNN}q\x0etq\x0fRq\x10.'
```

You could, thus, either do what @Majaha suggests (and bookend the call to `broadcast`) or you could patch the code to make the replacement that I outline above (where needed, but eh...), or you may be able to make your own derived class that does the job using `dill`:

```
>>> from pyspark.broadcast import Broadcast as _Broadcast
>>>
>>> class Broadcast(_Broadcast):
...   def dump(self, value, f):
...     try:
...       import dill
...       dill.dump(value, f, pickle_protocol)
...     ...[INSERT THE REST OF THE DUMP METHOD HERE]...
```

If the above fails... you could still get it to work by pinpointing where the serialization failure occurs (there's `dill.detect.trace` to help you with that).

If you are going to suggest to `pyspark` to use `dill`... a potentially better suggestion is to allow users to dynamically replace the serializer.  This is what `mpi4py` and a few other packages do.

Answer (score 0):

What's your location_to_explainer data schema? Maybe it better to transform to spark's dataframe.

According to [dill](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill) desciption

> dill can be used to store python objects to a file, but the primary usage is to send python objects across the network as a byte stream. dill is quite flexible, and allows arbitrary user defined classes and functions to be serialized. Thus dill is not intended to be secure against erroneously or maliciously constructed data. It is left to the user to decide whether the data they unpickle is from a trustworthy source.

And [When Not To Use pickle](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pickle-python-tutorial#not)

> If you want to use data across different programming languages, pickle is not recommended. Its protocol is specific to Python, thus, cross-language compatibility is not guaranteed. The same holds for different versions of Python itself. Unpickling a file that was pickled in a different version of Python may not always work properly, so you have to make sure that you're using the same version and perform an update if necessary. You should also try not to unpickle data from an untrusted source. Malicious code inside the file might be executed upon unpickling.

According to this [discuss](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/216#issuecomment-288747673) , you can try [pysparkling](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysparkling)

> I don't think this is a dill issue, as I don't think your code is using dill. So, as far as I know, pyspark uses pickle or cloudpickle and not dill. However, if you do want to use dill with pyspark, there is pysparkling (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysparkling)... and using it may clear up your serialization issue. What I suggest is that you open a ticket with pyspark or try pysparkling and if it fails, open a ticket there -- and CC me or refer to this issue so I can follow the thread. I'm going to close this... so if I'm incorrect and you are using dill, please feel free to reopen this issue.

Read more [Reading pyspark pickles locally](https://blog.sourced.tech/post/reading_pyspark_pickles_locally/)